# Retrieve all data from one table, and some from another in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join

In my CakePHP site, I want to make a drop-down list of all `Venues`, and any `Restaurants` that have `is_venue=1`.

I've tried this in my events_controller:

```
        $venueOptions = array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'name_address'),
        'order' => array('name'),
        'join' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'restaurants',
                'alias' => 'Restaurants',
                'type' => 'inner',
                                    'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('restaurants.is_venue = 1')
            )
        ),
    );
    $venues = $this->Event->Venue->find('list', $venueOptions);
```

But it appears to still just be getting the venues.  I don't really need an association between the two, since their associations will both be with an event, not each other.

Where have I gone wrong?  Am I close, but just need to tweak this code, or am I just all-together doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something along the lines of:

```
<?php
    ....
    $v = $this->Venue->find( 'list' );
    $r = $this->Restaurant->find( 'list' );
    $venues = Set::merge( $v, $r );
    natcasesort( $venues );
    // print_r( $venues );

    $this->set( 'venues', $venues );
    ...
?>
```

Which is quite like the code above - I just use the Set class and make sure to Controller::set the variable to the view.

Also added some basic sorting to show you one option even though array sorting has nothing really specific to do with CakePHP.

Also fixed some bad variable names where I had originally used $venues, and $restaurants - changed to be consistently $v and $r.

Comment: What's the point of the Set::merge(  as opposed to the array_merge mentioned below?  (also - i assume you  mean merge($v, $r), correct?)

Comment: @Abba - With some alterations, this pretty much works - the only issue now, is - all the restaurants show up at the bottom instead of being in alphabetical order - any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: It's an array - try using some of the handy sorting functions built into php. http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php  -- Example edited to show natural case-insensitive sorting but there are a ton of options.

Comment: Set::merge is not an exact functional copy of array_merge. I prefer to use cake's classes for such things when they exist as I assume they were written to handle any cake specific edge cases and to work with their data structuring.

Comment: I've tried just about every PHP sort, asort, ksort...etc I could think of - they all make the array print_r NOTHING - not sure why.  I'll try natcasesort to see if that works, thanks!

Comment: @Abba - the suggested natcasesort changes the array into the number "1" - that's it :(

Comment: you are echoing out the natcasesort( array( ... )); which will return a 1 - since the sort function returns true.

Comment: You might need to do $venues = Set::merge( $v, $r ); natcasesort( $venues ); print_r( $venues );

Comment: Thanks very very much.  Honestly, you both answered my question and responded identically - I REALLY appreciate your help - I picked his for the "answer" mostly because he answered first.  Also, there are still a few variable minor code issues in your answer (ie finding Venue twice). But you certainly hit the nail on the head and lead me straight to the right answer.

Comment: Correction - Set::merge works, but array_merge in other answer does not retain key=>value relationship - so... you get the "answer".  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah - I would give him half the answer rep if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Join will not work if there's no relation between. `Venue` and `Restaurant`. You should call them separately and merge the results

```
$venues = $this->Event->Venue->find('list', $venueOptions);
$restaurants = $this->Event->Restaurant->find('list', array('conditions' => array('is_venue' => '1')));
$results = array_merge($venues, $restaurants);

// sort results
asort($results);
```

Comment: @Ish Kumar  With some alterations, this pretty much works - the only issue now, is - all the restaurants show up at the bottom instead of being in alphabetical order - any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: @Ish - I thought that'd work too, but it doesn't - when I try to print_r it, it prints nothing. :/

Comment: Make sure you are **NOT** doing it like this `$results = asort($results);` ? because `asort` is called by reference and return boolean.

Comment: unfortunately array_merge doesn't retain key=>value relationship

Comment: `$results = $venues + $restaurants` instead of `array_merge`